# How do you save a Tensorflow dataset to a file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, serialization, tensorflow-datasets

There are at least two more questions like this on SO but not a single one has been answered.

I have a dataset of the form:

```
<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((512,), (512,), (512,), ()), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32)>
```

and another of the form:

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 512), (None, 512), (None, 512), (None,)), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32)>
```

I have looked and looked but I can't find the code to save these datasets to files that can be loaded later. The closest I got was [this page in the TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/TFRecordWriter), which suggests serializing the tensors using `tf.io.serialize_tensor` and then writing them to a file using `tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter`.

However, when I tried this using the code:

```
dataset.map(tf.io.serialize_tensor)
writer = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter('mydata.tfrecord')
writer.write(dataset)
```

I get an error on the first line:

> TypeError: serialize_tensor() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

How can I modify the above (or do something else) to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TFRecordWriter` seems to be the most convenient option, but unfortunately it can only write datasets with a single tensor per element. Here are a couple of workarounds you can use. First, since all your tensors have the same type and similar shape, you can concatenate them all into one, and split them back later on load:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Write
a = tf.zeros((100, 512), tf.int32)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a, a, a, a[:, 0]))
print(ds)
# <TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((512,), (512,), (512,), ()), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32)>
def write_map_fn(x1, x2, x3, x4):
    return tf.io.serialize_tensor(tf.concat([x1, x2, x3, tf.expand_dims(x4, -1)], -1))
ds = ds.map(write_map_fn)
writer = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter('mydata.tfrecord')
writer.write(ds)

# Read
def read_map_fn(x):
    xp = tf.io.parse_tensor(x, tf.int32)
    # Optionally set shape
    xp.set_shape([1537])  # Do `xp.set_shape([None, 1537])` if using batches
    # Use `x[:, :512], ...` if using batches
    return xp[:512], xp[512:1024], xp[1024:1536], xp[-1]
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('mydata.tfrecord').map(read_map_fn)
print(ds)
# <MapDataset shapes: ((512,), (512,), (512,), ()), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32)>
```

But, more generally, you can simply have a separate file per tensor and then read them all:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Write
a = tf.zeros((100, 512), tf.int32)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a, a, a, a[:, 0]))
for i, _ in enumerate(ds.element_spec):
    ds_i = ds.map(lambda *args: args[i]).map(tf.io.serialize_tensor)
    writer = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter(f'mydata.{i}.tfrecord')
    writer.write(ds_i)

# Read
NUM_PARTS = 4
parts = []
def read_map_fn(x):
    return tf.io.parse_tensor(x, tf.int32)
for i in range(NUM_PARTS):
    parts.append(tf.data.TFRecordDataset(f'mydata.{i}.tfrecord').map(read_map_fn))
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(parts))
print(ds)
# <ZipDataset shapes: (<unknown>, <unknown>, <unknown>, <unknown>), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32)>
```

It is possible to have the whole dataset in a single file with multiple separate tensors per element, namely as a file of TFRecords containing `tf.train.Example`s, but I don't know if there is a way to create those within TensorFlow, that is, without having to get the data out of the dataset into Python and then write it to the records file.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot shortly and will get back to you. Am very grateful for your help! Have been struggling to get answers to TF-related questions on here lately.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have no idea how helpful that was!

Answer (score 10):

An incident was open on GitHUb and it appears there's a new feature available in TF 2.3 to write to disk :

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/save
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/load

I haven't tested this features yet but it seems to be doing what you want.

Comment: I'm experimenting with this. Couple of clunky things, but easy to get around: 1. If you specify GZIP compression, but don't make it obvious that it's gzipped, when you try to load it, if you don't specify `compression='GZIP'`, it'll load he data without complains, but when you try to use it, it'll say "data corrupted". Not obvious why it's corrupted. 2. You need to specify a tf.TypeSpec. Would be nice if tf.data.experimental.save created the required protobuf for you so you wouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Correction from the above comment: you need to specify a `tf.TensorSpec` (slightly different). But what is unfortunate from my brief experimenting with it: the size of the file is huge. I have a parquet file (gzipped) with 7M rows of mostly `uint16`s, at 277MB. The `tf.dataset.experimental.save` artifact (several directories and "shards"), which has fewer "columns" than the parquet file, but is also gzipped, is over 600MB.

Comment: Tensorflow 2.9 docs say this is deprecated https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/save

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72858773/5931672) the code on how to use it. It was too long for a comment XD

Answer (score 6):

To add on Yoan's answer:

the tf.experimental.save() and load() API works well. You also need to MANUALLY save the ds.element_spec to disk to be able to load() later / within a different context.

Pickling works well for me:

1- Saving:

```
tf.data.experimental.save(
    ds, tf_data_path, compression='GZIP'
)
with open(tf_data_path + '/element_spec', 'wb') as out_:  # also save the element_spec to disk for future loading
    pickle.dump(ds.element_spec, out_)
```

2- For loading, you need both the folder path with the tf shards and the element_spec that we manually pickled

```
with open(tf_data_path + '/element_spec', 'rb') as in_:
    es = pickle.load(in_)

loaded = tf.data.experimental.load(
    tf_data_path, es, compression='GZIP'
)
```

Comment: With TF 2.5+ you can use tf.data.experimental.save(...) and load without the element spec. But with older versions of TF (like 2.4-) this seems to be the approach.

Answer (score 5):

Tensorflow 2.10 moved the [save](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.10/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#save) method from `tf.data.experimental` to `tf.data.Dataset`.  Used with the [load](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.10/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#load) method, this is the easiest way to, well, save and load a model.

Tensorflow 2.6 introduced the [snapshot](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.6/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#snapshot) method (previously an "experimental" feature).  [Tensorflow RFC-193](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20200107-tf-data-snapshot.md) goes into detail on the motivation and details of the feature.

From the docs:

> The snapshot API allows users to transparently persist the output of their preprocessing pipeline to disk, and materialize the pre-processed data on a different training run.
>
> This API enables repeated preprocessing steps to be consolidated, and allows re-use of already processed data, trading off disk storage and network bandwidth for freeing up more valuable CPU resources and accelerator compute time.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of Nov 2022

Comment: It seems that certain inherited types like <PrefetchedDataset> may not have this? How would one use this feature on them?

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on this issus as well and so far I have written the following util (as to be found [in my repo as well](https://github.com/few-shot-learning/Keras-FewShotLearning/blob/master/keras_fsl/utils/datasets.py))

```py
def cache_with_tf_record(filename: Union[str, pathlib.Path]) -> Callable[[tf.data.Dataset], tf.data.TFRecordDataset]:
    """
    Similar to tf.data.Dataset.cache but writes a tf record file instead. Compared to base .cache method, it also insures that the whole
    dataset is cached
    """

    def _cache(dataset):
        if not isinstance(dataset.element_spec, dict):
            raise ValueError(f"dataset.element_spec should be a dict but is {type(dataset.element_spec)} instead")
        Path(filename).parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(str(filename)) as writer:
            for sample in dataset.map(transform(**{name: tf.io.serialize_tensor for name in dataset.element_spec.keys()})):
                writer.write(
                    tf.train.Example(
                        features=tf.train.Features(
                            feature={
                                key: tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value.numpy()]))
                                for key, value in sample.items()
                            }
                        )
                    ).SerializeToString()
                )
        return (
            tf.data.TFRecordDataset(str(filename), num_parallel_reads=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
            .map(
                partial(
                    tf.io.parse_single_example,
                    features={name: tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string) for name in dataset.element_spec.keys()},
                ),
                num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE,
            )
            .map(
                transform(
                    **{name: partial(tf.io.parse_tensor, out_type=spec.dtype) for name, spec in dataset.element_spec.items()}
                )
            )
            .map(
                transform(**{name: partial(tf.ensure_shape, shape=spec.shape) for name, spec in dataset.element_spec.items()})
            )
        )

    return _cache
```

With this util, I can do:

```py
dataset.apply(cache_with_tf_record("filename")).map(...)
```

and also load directly the dataset for later use with only the second part of the util.

I am still working on it so it may change later on, especially to serialize with the correct types instead of all bytes to save space (I guess).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tf.data.experimental.save](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/save) and  [tf.data.experimental.load](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/load) like this:

Code to save it:

```
tf_dataset = get_dataset()    # returns a tf.data.Dataset() file
tf.data.experimental.save(dataset=tf_dataset, path="path/to/desired/save/file_name")
with open("path/to/desired/save/file_name" + ".pickle", 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(tf_dataset.element_spec, file)   # I need this for opening it later
```

Code to open:

```
element_spec = pickle.load("path/to/desired/save/file_name" + ".pickle", 'rb')
tensor_data = tf.data.experimental.load("path/to/desired/save/file_name", element_spec=element_spec)
```