# How to save and use a Tensorflow dataset using the Experimental save and load mehods?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I wrote two python files create_save.py and load_use.py as shown below.
create_save.py is running good and saving tf dataset.

But load_use.py is giving errors shown below.
How to fix load_use.py errors please?

create_save.py

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.data.experimental import save as tf_save
ds_dir = os.path.join('./', "save_load_tfds_dir")
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(12)
tf_save(ds, ds_dir)
```

load_use.py

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
ds_dir = os.path.join('./', "save_load_tfds_dir")
new_ds = tf.data.experimental.load(ds_dir)
for elem in new_ds:
  print(elem)
```

Above load_use.py program is giving following errors:

> TypeError     Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 new_ds = tf.data.experimental.load(ds_dir)
>
> TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'element_spec'

How to fix above error?

Answer (score 1):

To load a previously saved dataset, you need to specify **element_spec** argument -- a type signature of the elements of the saved dataset, which can be obtained via tf.data.Dataset.element_spec. This requirement exists so that shape inference of the loaded dataset does not need to perform I/O.

```
import tempfile
path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "saved_data")
# Save a dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(2)
tf.data.experimental.save(dataset, path)
new_dataset = tf.data.experimental.load(path,
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64))  # element_spec arg
for elem in new_dataset:
  print(elem)
```

When you are creating a `tf.data.Dataset`, it has the attribute `element_spec` which is what you should be using while loading your saved file. (Refer: [Dataset doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#attributes_1)).

In the above example, the `element_spec` argument in the `load()` method is given as per the type specification of the data being saved in the code.

[TF Data Load Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/load)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for fast answer. For real programs, element_spec is large. Is there an automatic way to save TensorSpec value in create_save.py  ?

Comment: Is there an automatic way to get element spec? a type signature of the elements of the saved dataset, which can be obtained via tf.data.Dataset.element_spec.

Comment: How to convert TensorSpec tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64) element_spec to a string?
And how to convert string  'tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64)' to TensorSpec element spec please?

Comment: TensorSpec can be thought of as a signature of the data you are loading. The idea is that when you provide this tensor specifications information, the `load` method will know how to load. I would suggest you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61720708/3577783) for more ways to save a dataset than using experimental versions

Comment: Thank you mb0850. I will look at the link you have given.